# Trying to allow only certain strings into the URL bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsstring

To sum it up, I have a browser in my app, and I want it to only launch 5 websites, nothing else. Is there a way I can make my browser just launch the 5 websites by setting customs strings, like an if {user types this string in} go to that and then else {do not load}

Here is the code I have for the URL part

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

// go to google.com
NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlRequest];

// set text bar
urlbar.text = [urlRequest absoluteString];

// load request
[webView loadRequest:request];

// show loading icon
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}
```

And sorry if it is not too in detail, or if I am missing something, I would say I am a beginner to this.

Here is the additional code I had

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil: (UINavigationController *)navigationController: (Controller *)transmission
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    self.controller = navigationController;
    self.libtransmission = transmission;
}
return self;
}

- (IBAction)go:(id)sender
{ 
// create url request
NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:urlbar.text];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlRequest];

// load request
[webView loadRequest:request];

// make network icon visible
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
 // update urlbar
urlbar.text = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

// make the loading icon disappear
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the sites that can be accessed into an array, and then go through that array to see if the string typed in is in that array, like this

```
NSArray *sites = @[@"http://test.com", @"http://test1.com", @"http://test2.com", @"http://test3.com", @"http://test4.com"];
NSString *urlToOpen = URLTextField.text;
for (NSString *str in sites){
    if ([urlToOpen isEqualToString:str]){
        NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToOpen];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlRequest];
        urlbar.text = [urlRequest absoluteString];
        [webView loadRequest:request];

    }
    else{
        //url user entered is not one of the 5 urls
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. This makes a lot of sense to me, never thought of this way of doing it, but I encountered one problem when plugging it into Xcode. When I did so, it received an error message for URLTextField.text, saying it was an unused property. I'm guessing I have to declare the property in the h and m files, but with the M file, what would I need to declare under the property? This may not even be the problem, but any thoughts?

Comment: Well, in my answer, `URLTextField` is just an example for whatever the textfield you have people enter addresses into is called. Replace it with whatever that text field is called.

Comment: Alright urlbar.text has been the only thing to appease the warning so far, but it does not seem to work regardless when I run. Is there anything else you could suggest (I posted more code up above), I am dumfounded right now and probably way over-thinking this.

Comment: Have you replaced the objects in the `sites` array with your URLs? And are you sure urlbar is set up correctly and is not nil?

Comment: I will sleep on this. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hey plugged it into the right spot, and finally was working. Thank you very much for helping me with this.